# How to fix unknown skin name 'WVGA800' error when setting up GitLab CI?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm new to CI and I'm trying to setup CI on GitLab for Android and here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
 ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "27"
 ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "24.0.0"
 ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"

before_script:
 - apt-get --quiet update --yes
 - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
 - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz  https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-   linux.tgz
 - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
 - mkdir android-sdk-linux/licenses
 - printf "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55\nd56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" > android-sdk-linux/licenses/android-sdk-license
 - printf "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > android-sdk-linux/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
 - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
 - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
 - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
 - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
 - build
 - test

build:
 stage: build
 script:
 - ./gradlew assembleDebug
artifacts:
 paths:
 - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:
 stage: test
 script:
   - ./gradlew test

functionalTests:
 stage: test
 script:
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
  - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-x86-google_apis-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -n avd$AVD_SDK -t android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK} --abi google_apis/x86
  - android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd avd$AVD_SDK -no-window -no-audio &
  - ./android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - ./gradlew cAT
artifacts:
  paths:
  - app/build/reports/androidTests/
```

My above script builds my app but when it's running functionalTest I got this error:
`emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'WVGA800'`
then I've created my AVD with `-no-skin` parameter and now I got this error:

```
$ android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd avd$AVD_SDK -no-skin -no-window -no-audio &
$ ./android-wait-for-emulator
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (/builds/myRepo/myProject/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/) but cannot find kernel file in /builds/myRepo/myProject/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/system-images/ sub directories
```

I've followed [this guide](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/02/14/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/) but not really helped to me. Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this problem?